# Xamarin.Forms ListView Cell reuse?

Tags: ios, listview, memory, cell, xamarin.forms

So I was fooling around with Xamarin.Forms and the TodoMVVM sample ( https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/TodoMvvm) and I noticed in Instruments that when I scroll the list the number of UILabels keeps increasing and seems to never be released which eventually will lead to a crash.

Is there a way to modify the example so that the cells are properly release/reused?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you asked this question, cells were not being reused, but they're now. Still there are other problems with memory allocation, but progress is being done.

Source:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/31759/listview-cells-being-cached